# Why isn't :normal /pattern<CR> working on vim

Tags: vim

I have these 4 lines:

```
the lazy cow jumped over the high moon
the hazy cow jumped over the high moon
the noble cow jumped over the high moon
the crazy cow jumped over the high moon
```

`:normal dd` is working as expected.

Why doesn't `:normal /over<CR>` highlight anything ?

I apologize for asking a such basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`:h :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal):

```
{commands} should be a complete command.  If
{commands} does not finish a command, the last one
will be aborted as if <Esc> or <C-C> was typed.
```

To complete a `/pattern` you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you're actually finishing the `:normal` command, so the `/pattern` remains incomplete.

You can include the <kbd>Enter</kbd> as part of the command by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
:normal /over^M
```

Vim will show <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as `^M`. See [`:h c_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-V).